# How does forum determine new replies for each user?

Tags: 7, nodes

When I visit `drupal.org/forum/*`, in `Replies` column I can see how many new posts have been added. Drupal also marks them with a `New` tag.

I'm wondering how does drupal determine which replies are new for me? Are they new since my last visit to the page, or my last logout from drupal.org? In case the later is correct, how does drupal know when I loggeout out last time?

I'm very interested to know what algorithm is behind this nice feature?

Comment: It's pretty low tech, just these few lines of code: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_mark/7

Comment: @Clive Thanks for the tip but I'm drupal-illiterate. Can you explain it in plain English or pseudo-code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal has a `history` table to record when any user viewed any node.

So it knows when you last viewed the node, and which comments have newer timestamps. So it marks those comments with newer timestamps as `new` or `updated`.

**UPDATE:** There is also a constant `NODE_NEW_LIMIT` set in the `node.module` file which defaults to 30 days ago. That means nodes changed before 30 days are always marked as read.